# Problem with Solve a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, mathematica

I Have a little problem . I wrote this function ( function describe dynamics of ball-hoop system):

```
soln = NDSolve[{7000*q''[t] + 20000*q[t] - 800*f''[t]*f[t] == 0, 
    896*f''[t] - 480*h''[t] + 7848*f[t] - 800*q''[t]*f[t] == 0,
    900*h''[t] - 480*f''[t] + 20000*h[t] == 0,
    q[0] == 0.1, h[0] == 0.1, f[0] == 0.},
   {q[t], f[t], h[t]},
   {t, 0, 5}];)
```

After i run it,program show mi this comunicate

```
NDSolve::deqn: "Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument "Here is my code", False, h[0] == 0.1`, False}\). "
```

Anybody now what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this `Mathematica` code, please enter the following instead:

soln = NDSolve[{7000*q''[t] + 20000*q[t] - 800*f''[t]*f[t] == 0, 
                 896*f''[t] - 480*h''[t] + 7848*f[t] - 800*q''[t]*f[t] == 0,
                 900*h''[t] - 480*f''[t] + 20000*h[t] == 0,
                q[0] == 0.1, h[0] == 0.1, f[0] == 0.},
               {q[t], f[t], h[t]},
               {t, 0, 5}]

Removing the last couple of characters should do ok to solve the problem.